# Populate 2DArray with data from file

Tags: java, variable-assignment, multidimensional-array

My file contains some data

> [[22, 19, 23], [19, 10, 16], [12, 15, 8]]

which I want to read from, and populate them into a 2D Array.

Below is my attempt:

```
private static void eFile() {
    String kF;

    System.out.println("K:");
    kF = mainInput.nextLine();

    if (kf.equalsIgnoreCase("kf.txt")) {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            String line = null;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("kf.txt"));
            int[][] matrix = null;
            String[] keys = null;
            int key = 0;

            if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                keys = line.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
                        .replace(",", "").split(" ");
                matrix = new int[(int) Math.sqrt(keys.length)][(int) Math
                        .sqrt(keys.length)];

                System.out.println("File elements: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    key = Integer.parseInt(keys[i]);
                    System.out.println(key); // Able to print normally.
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++) {
                            matrix[j][k] = key; // Problematic line
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Matrix elements: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++) {
                    System.out.println(matrix[j][k]); // All same numbers
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    } else {
        System.out
                .println("Please rename your file to kf.txt");
    }
}
```

But the output turns out otherwise

> File elements:
>   22
>   19
>   23
>   19
>   10
>   16
>   12
>   15
>   8
>   Matrix elements: 
>   8
>   8
>   8
>   8
>   8
>   8
>   8
>   8
>   8

Supposed to be:

> File elements:
>   22
>   19
>   23
>   19
>   10
>   16
>   12
>   15
>   8
>   Matrix elements: 
>   22
>   19
>   23
>   19
>   10
>   16
>   12
>   15
>   8

Comment: why do you set matrix[j][k] = key;

Comment: Because I want to populate the array? o.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here modify as below

```
int keyIndex = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++) {
        matrix[j][k] = Integer.parseInt(keys[keyIndex]); // Problematic line
             keyIndex = keyIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

And, to print the `matrix` use `Arrays.deepToString()` like

```
Arrays.deepToString(matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Been stuck for a few hours :S